Understanding ZIO.Schedule
I am trying to figure out how to idiomatically use zio.Schedule. I see it has State, Input, and Output, but can't understand how I can make use of them.
For example, suppose, I have a utility function, that keeps trying some effect on a given schedule until it succeeds:
def keepTrying[A])(f: Task[A])(policy: Schedule[Any, Any, Any]: Promise[A] = for {
   promise <- Promise.make[Throwable, A]
   _ <- f.retry(policy)
    .flatMap(promise.succeed)
    .unit
    .forkDaemon 
} yield promise

I think this works (does it?) ... But what if I wanted to modify this function to log its attempts with information about the failure and number of tries so far, like
log(s"Retry #$n failed with $error")
What is an idiomatic way to do this? Is it possible to manipulate policy somehow to get a callback with this information after each attempt?

You can use the tapOutput of Schedule:
val policy: Schedule[Any, Any, T] = ???

val policyWithLogs: Schedule[Any, Any, T] = 
  policy.tapOutput { t: T =>
    ZIO.log("Retrying...")
  }

However, this requires you to have an "output" type in your Schedule containing some useful data.
This is the case with out-the-box policies though:
Schedule.recurs(...) // Schedule[Any, Any, Long]
Schedule.exponential(...) // Schedule[Any, Any, Duration]


From any policy, you can get a policy that does the same thing and also output the number of attempts by combining it with the forever policy.

Schedule.forever
A schedule that always recurs, producing a count of repeats: 0, 1, 2.

val policy: Schedule[Any, Any, T] = ???

val policyWithCounter: Schedule[Any, Any, (T, Long)] = 
  policy && Schedule.forever

val policyWithLogs: Schedule[Any, Any, (T, Long)] = 
  policyWithCounter.tapOutput {
    case (_, count) =>
      ZIO.log(s"Retrying $count ...")
  }


Right, that was kinda my question - how do I make a Schedule with the output I need? E.g., if I wanted to log the number of the attempt.

@Dima I've updated my answer. I hope it helps.

yeah, that's pretty cool, thanks! But I was wondering if there is some sort of a more generic way to control inputs and outputs to pass arbitrary state between attempts?

TBH I don't know. I didn't use that much the retries strategies yet :)
